# HTTP equivalent of HTML <title> tag for non-HTML files?

Tags: http, http-headers, cgi, title

Can an HTTP header value or another technique be used to set the title in Browsers' windows/tabs for a plain-text file?

When sending a file to the browser with `Content-Type: text/plain` or similar, the title in the browser window/tab is usually the address to the script or file. Adding a `<title>` tag to the `<head>` section of HTML will set the title to a name of your choice, but that option is only possible if you're using `Content-Type: text/html` or similar.

Let's say that my script currently outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=SomeFile.txt

Hello, World!
```

A browser will interpret this to mean a text (*.txt) file using UTF-8 encoding with a single line saying `Hello, World!`. It will also know to use "SomeFile.txt" as the file name when saving. But the name in the browser window/tab will be something like "http://some.host.com/myscript.cgi" when I'd prefer either "SomeFile.txt" or "Some File".

I'd like to set the file with something simple like an HTTP header (E.g. `Content-Title: Some File` or `Content-Disposition: inline; title="Some File"; filename=SomeFile.txt`).

How should I communicate this title preference to a Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does pick up on `Content-Disposition`’s `filename` like you want. You can see this by visiting a Wikia image, like [`https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/d/db/Armcannons.png/revision/latest?cb=20140820011953`](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/d/db/Armcannons.png/revision/latest?cb=20140820011953), where the supplied `filename` is displayed in the tab title.

Unfortunately, Chrome and Safari both display `latest` instead, from the last segment of the URL’s path. (Firefox will also do this in the absence of `Content-Disposition`.) So if you want this to work in every browser, you may need to append a path segment containing the URL-encoded string you want to display to the end of the URL, and then configure your script/application router/`.htaccess`/whatever to ignore that last part when finding the file. For your example, the URL would look something like:

`https://example.com/SomeFile.txt/Some%20File`

### Research dead ends

- `Link: <>; rel=self; title="Some File"` is the most correct option I found, but doesn’t influence browsers.
- [Some ancient Windows documentation mentions a `Content-Name` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/mc-bup/c38e5971-5d67-450c-b2a7-8df140fbebab), but the trail goes cold from there — no RFC seems to mention it.
- MIME and Usenet headers used `Subject` for this purpose, but no web browser seems to respect that.

Comment: While it isn't *just* a header, adding the server-side-ignored filename at the end of the path does accomplish the goal, and it's very clever. I certainly think you've earned both my appreciation and an accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a) Your example of Content-Disposition is broken; the disposition type is mandatory; see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.4.1

b) And no, there is no title parameter, nor do I think there is another way to communicate this to the browser.

Comment: I fixed the Content-Disposition line in the question to reflect RFC6266. All my test browsers recognize incomplete Content-Dispositions, so it's easy to forget that the disposition-type is technically required.